# check for anagram in pair of input given as phrase = A, B. where A and B are 2 words

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is the code I wrote. but it gives True/False for each alphabet. I want the output to give me a single true or false. what changes should I make?

```
Z = input()
Y = Z.split()
M = list(Y[0])
N = list(Y[1])

M.pop(-1)

for i in range(len(N)):
    print(M.count(M[i]) == N.count(N[i]))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+anagram

Answer (score 1):

I would take another approach. If you sort the letters of both words and compare them against each other, then you will get a single `True` if the words are anagrams of each other:

```
>>> def is_anagram(word1, word2):
...   return sorted(word1) == sorted(word2)
>>> is_anagram('elbow', 'below')
>>> True
>>> is_anagram('elbow', 'lower')
>>> False
```

Comment: Z = input()

Y = Z.split(", ")
print(sorted(Y[0]) == sorted(Y[1])). Thanks. I edited my code to this. can't use def(function) yet. haven't been taught that yet

Answer (score 0):

Check my code:

```
A = "a decimal point".replace(" ","")
B = "i m a dot in place".replace(" ","")


def checkAnagram(A,B):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        
        if(A.count(A[i])!=B.count(A[i])):
            return False
    return True

         
if(len(A)!=len(B)):
        print("Pair is not anagram.")
else:
    if(checkAnagram(A,B)):
        print("pair is anagram")
    else:
        print("Pair is not Anagram")
```